# Application Created with Processing.org Won't Launch on Linux

Tags: linux, processing, linux-mint

I have created an application using Processing.org. Everything works fine when I "Export Application" and run it on my Mac. When I "Export Application" and move the application.linux folder to my computer that is running Linux Mint, I click the Shell Script file and nothing happens.

Any ideas what could be the cause of this? I am not particularly practiced with Linux, so it could be something basic.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you try to run it in a terminal to see if some errors are displayed?

Comment: Did you add execution privileges to your script? `sudo chmod +x myscript`

Comment: I figured it out. I was using the mime library for sound and for whatever reason that was not working on linux, so I just commented out all the sound functions for now - will have to figure it out later. Also had to right-click on the shell file and set permissions to "Make This File Executable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue here was that once I got the file onto the Linux machine I had to right-click on the shell file and set permissions to "Make This File Executable"